# MonoTouch CoolStorage OneToMany caching issue

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, coolstorage

I'm experiencing an issue with CoolStorage where a OneToMany relationship is being cached when reading a list for the first time, that list then fails to update when the data changes later.

When restarting my app the list is correct, so it must be a caching issue and I can't find the solution in the CoolStorage documentation or anywhere.

I've pasted my Unit test code below.

I have a Game class that has an Opponent of type Person. There are many Games, and a Person can be an Opponent for many Games.

My Person class has a `CSList` called OpponentGames, so at anytime for that Person I can say 'get the games where this person is the Opponent'.

In the unit test the first time I reference 'person.OpponentGames.Count', it correctly tells me there is one game. After creating a second game and adding my person as the opponent, it still reports one game for OpponentGames.

If I remove the first count, the test passes, so the first check result is being cached and from there it's not updated.

I'll greatly appreciate any suggestions!! Thanks.

The `SQL (sqlite3)` setup:

```
CSDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "CREATE TABLE Person " +
    "(ServerId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");

CSDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "CREATE TABLE Game " +
    "(ServerId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
    "OpponentId INTEGER REFERENCES User(ServerId))");
```

The CoolStorage .Net classes:

```
[MapTo("Game")]
public class Game : CSObject<Game,int>
{
    //[PrimaryKey]
    public int ServerId { get { return (int) GetField("ServerId"); } set { SetField("ServerId", value); } }

    [ManyToOne (LocalKey="OpponentId", ForeignKey="ServerId")]
    public Person Opponent { get { return (Person) GetField("Opponent"); } set { SetField("Opponent", value); } }
}

[MapTo("Person")]
public class Person : CSObject<Person,int>
{
    //[PrimaryKey]
    public int ServerId { get { return (int) GetField("ServerId"); } set { SetField("ServerId", value); } }

    [OneToMany (LocalKey="ServerId", ForeignKey="OpponentId")]
    public CSList<Game> OpponentGames { get { return (CSList<Game>) GetField("OpponentGames"); } }
}
```

And finally, the Unit test:

```
// user

Person person = Person.New ();
person.ServerId = 1;

// first game

Game game = Game.New ();
game.ServerId = 1;
game.Opponent = person;

game.Save ();
person.Save ();

// this line correctly returns 1, removing this passes the test

Console.WriteLine ("count0: " + person.OpponentGames.Count);

// second game

Game game2 = Game.New ();

game2.ServerId = 2;
game2.Opponent = person;

game2.Save ();
person.Save ();

// this incorrectly shows 1, should be 2

Console.WriteLine ("count1: " + person.OpponentGames.Count);

// and it fails

Assert.True (person.OpponentGames.Count == 2);
```